# Xamarin.Forms: Tapped event on CheckBox control

Tags: c#, events, xamarin.forms, checkbox

Is there a way to recognize something like Tapped event on the CheckBox control?
CheckedChanged event is also triggered at the creation of the container (in my case a CollectionView) and at the scroll too, instead I need to manage the change of state only at the user's tap.
I'm trying to use GestureRecognizers, but the command is fired only if I tap on StackLayout. If I tap on CheckBox nothing happens.

```
    <CollectionView 
        x:Name="LvSospesi" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListaSospesi}"           
        SelectedItem="{Binding SospesoModelCorrente, Mode=TwoWay}">
        
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SospesoModel">
                <Grid 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding BindingContext.ListaSospesiEnabled, Source={x:Reference RootPage}}">
                                            
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>      
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>      
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource AltezzaRigheGriglieArticoli}"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.Row="0">

                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.CheckSospesoCommand, Source={x:Reference RootPage}}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        
                        <CheckBox 
                            InputTransparent="True"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Selezionato}">                                
                        </CheckBox>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to use tapped event. But to say what I would do, need more details: Explain how the checkboxes are used. Do they always start unchecked, or do you set their state based on boolean values somewhere?

Comment: I updated my question with code sample. CheckBox are unchecked on start, and the state can change by user or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Make the input of your checkbox transparent using InputTransparent and Wrap it in a Stack or some other layout and get the events from your Layout

```
<StackLayout>  <!--This will now take your checkbox click events and you can wrap it under other layouts-->
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>    
          <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding CheckboxTappedCommand}"
            />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>    
  <CheckBox InputTransparent= "True" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thx. I applied your suggestion, and I set InputTransparent = true for the CheckBox control, but the Command (I use the mvvm pattern) on StackLayout.GestureRecognizers only fires when I click on the StackLayout area, while if I tap on the checkBox nothing happens.

Comment: Use a Command  in the gesture recognizor as the tap event for checkbox, i have updated above answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but still nothing happens on checkBox click. Seems that InputTransparent value is ignored. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you show me how your updated code looks like, may be i can help you!

Comment: I updated my question with code sample.

Comment: Can you confirm if your bindings are working?

Comment: Yes, it works. The binding class SospesoModel inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged. I've the issue even if I remove binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246849/discussion-between-freakyali-and-kronos).

Answer (score 0):

Tap gesture will not directly work on checkbox, even if input transparent property is set to true. You have to place checkbox inside grid and place some box view with transparent background above checkbox and listen tapped event/command from box view

```
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    InputTransparent="True"/>
                <BoxView
                    Color="Transparent">
                    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnCheck_Changed"/>
                    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                </BoxView>
            <Grid>
```